# UITapGestureRecognize with UILabel get the labels text in function

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitapgesturerecognizer, clickable

I have a Label for a phone number and an email. If you click on the email label, the mail app should open with the mail defined inside the label.

That is my function:

```
func tapMailFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("tapMail working")
}
```

Inside the cellForRowAt i set the following:

```
cell.Mail.addGestureRecognizer(tapMail)
```

That is how my UITapGestureRecognizer looks like:

```
let tapMail = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: Selector(TestViewController.tapMailFunction))
```

How can get the cell.Mail.text inside my function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the recognizer object to get the related view. Something like this:

```
func tapMailFunction(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let label = sender.view as? UILabel {
        let text = label.text
    }
}
```